# ¿Cómo puedo quitar el salto de línea en una columna usando Awk?

Tags: awk

Tengo algo como esto:

```
Arena               Gig1/46       Gig1/0/49
CUCMS4              Gig7/35       eth0
SALUD-3750-P1R4v-dis    
Gig1/7        Gig1/0/12
CUCMS5              Gig7/33       eth0
EMMA_6              Gig1/36       Gig1/0/49
```

Necesito una salida como esta:

```
Arena               Gig1/46       Gig1/0/49
CUCMS4              Gig7/35       eth0
SALUD-3750-P1R4v-dis Gig1/7        Gig1/0/12
CUCMS5              Gig7/33       eth0
EMMA_6              Gig1/36       Gig1/0/49
```

He probado con este comando pero no elimina el salto de línea:

```
awk -F, '{gsub("\n","",$1); print}' archivo.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente valida si una línea contiene 3 campos. Si no es así, guarda el valor e imprímelo en la siguiente línea:

```
$ awk 'NF<3{if (linea) {print linea, $0; linea=""; next} linea=$0; next}1' fichero
Arena               Gig1/46       Gig1/0/49
CUCMS4              Gig7/35       eth0
SALUD-3750-P1R4v-dis     Gig1/7        Gig1/0/12
CUCMS5              Gig7/33       eth0
EMMA_6              Gig1/36       Gig1/0/49
```

Esto es:

```
NF<3{                        # si la línea tiene menos de 3 campos
     if (linea) {            # si "linea" está definido
           print linea, $0;  # imprime lo guardado seguido de la línea actual
           linea="";         # resetea la variable "linea"
           next              # salta a la siguiente línea
    }
    linea=$0;                # en caso contrario, guarda la línea actual
    next                     # y salta a la siguiente línea
 }
1                            # si no ha pasado nada de lo anterior,
                             # imprime la línea actual
```

```py
import this
print(42)
```

Answer (score 2):

Debido a que awk lee datos basados en línea, debe buscar la siguiente línea cuando hay menos de tres campos. Por ejemplo:

```
awk 'NF != 3 { printf "%s", $0; getline; gsub("\n", "") } 1' archivo.txt
```

Salida:

```
Arena               Gig1/46       Gig1/0/49
CUCMS4              Gig7/35       eth0
SALUD-3750-P1R4v-dis    Gig1/7        Gig1/0/12
CUCMS5              Gig7/33       eth0
EMMA_6              Gig1/36       Gig1/0/49
```